# How to find list of databases from Security Logins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My basic concern is to find which database/s I have access to using query...

In the following image, I need to write a query to find list of databases mapped to the user. In following example list will contain Cal and San.....

I can retrieve this loginname by using following query

```
select loginname from syslogins where name = (SELECT SUSER_NAME() LoggedInUser)
```

How can I find database list from that?

[image]

Thanks a lot,
Omkar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the system procedure sp_helplogins to get this information:

```
declare @loginName sysname;
set @loginName = suser_name();
exec sp_helplogins @loginName;
```

Its likely more information than you need. If so, look at the code of that procedure as example to write your own procedure (its best not to rely on system procedures anyways, as they can be changed by Microsoft).

Comment: Ok there will be multiple user who wants to check which database/s they have access to. Some of them may not have permission for sp_helplogins..... Can you give me a query where user can know databases to whom he has access to?

Comment: This answer tells you what to do: open up the SP and then write your own from it

Comment: It says User does not have permission to perform this action.

Comment: Is this exposed in an application or are users executing it against the db directly?